# ubuntu - sudo pecl command not found

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, sudo, pecl

I'm using ubuntu 12.04

I installed php pear using this command

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
```

I got this results

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php-pear is already the newest version.
php5-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Now when I use this command

```
sudo pecl install v8js-0.1.3
```

I'm getting this error

```
sudo: pecl: command not found
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this error?
Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Find your instance of `pecl`. i.e. `which` or `locate`

Check for **secure_path** on sudo

```
[root@host ~]# sudo -V | grep 'Value to override'
Value to override user's $PATH with: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

If `$PATH` is being overriden us `visudo` and edit `/etc/sudoers` and append the path to pecl

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

We need PEAR! For some reason, it's not set up ready to on Lion, but the install phar file is here, so we just need to run it.

cd /usr/lib/php
sudo php install-pear-nozlib.phar

Edit:
/etc/php.ini and find the line: ;
  include_path = ".:/php/includes" 
and change it to:
  include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php/pear"
sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net
sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
sudo pear upgrade-all

Answer (score 0):

The simple way that worked for me is by browsing to the folder where your pecl located thru your nautilus explorer and double click pecl icon. then after that you might type `sudo pecl install whatever`